# Resize Error - Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, styles, paperclip

I just installed paperclip into my app to upload images, and everything was working well until I tried to add the styles to make the image resize. (I can upload images fine before I add this code)

on pins.rb:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>" }
```

I then added the class to on _pin.html.rb:

```
<td><%= image_tag pin.image(:medium) %></td>
```

But now, when I try and upload an image, I get the error:

```
Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError
```

When I remove the styles, it works fine (alebit not resized), but something in the resizing is messing it all up. I tried different file types and filenames. I have searched for this error on google, and all the solutions aren't working for me. The most popular was to downgrade Cocaine, but when I try that it I get the message:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "cocaine":
In Gemfile:
paperclip (~> 3.4.1) ruby depends on
cocaine (~> 0.5.0) ruby

cocaine (0.3.2)
```

My rails server is returning the message:

```
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-22 21:50:05 -0400
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
[2013-03-22 21:50:05] WARN Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Any help? I have it on github at https://github.com/jeremybelcher/omrails if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

To answer Rich Peck's question, you don't have to add it into the model directly - you can add it into /config/environments/development.rb. That way it'll only affect your dev version and not your production version.

So in my case, I just added

`Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16'`

to the end of my config/environments/development.rb file and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same issue with the same omrails assignment - rebooting my machine fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't installed imagemagick and haven't pointed to it in your application.

As stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip):

> ImageMagick must be installed and Paperclip must have access to it. To
>   ensure that it does, on your command line, run `which convert` (one of
>   the ImageMagick utilities). This will give you the path where that
>   utility is installed. For example, it might return
>   /usr/local/bin/convert.
>
> In development mode, you might add this line to
>   config/environments/development.rb):

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do it. It was working fine until I tried adding a style to resize the images upon upload.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and fixed it by including **`Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "YOUR_PATH_TO_IMAGE_MAGICK"` in the upload model (in my case image.rb):**

(Windows 7, Rails 4 & Ruby 2.0):

```
#Image Upload 
has_attached_file :image,
    :command_path => 'C:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick',
    :styles => { :medium => "x300", :thumb => "x100" },
    :default_url => "xxxxx",
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => 'xxxxxx',
    :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS
```

Still working on making it conditional for development & production

Answer (score 0):

1- I have the same issue, and I solved it, when i configure the dynamic linker run-time bindings to create the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries using the [ldconfig command](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig).

So you need to use the following command:

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

Actually, I advice to re-install imagemagick using steps at [how-to-install-image-magick-and-setup-paperclip](http://robmclarty.com/blog/how-to-install-image-magick-and-setup-paperclip).

2- You need to add the following code in `development.rb` file:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```