# Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, upload, imagemagick, paperclip, identify

I am trying to upload image with paperclip, but got this error:

```
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIden tifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
```

I found several similar cases with mine. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249770/papercliperrorsnotidentifiedbyimagemagickerror) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582583/resize-error-papercliperrorsnotidentifiedbyimagemagickerror). But I didn't use gem cocaine and my image file name is 01.png (without colons).
I don't know what the problem is. Anyone?

By the way, this is my Gemfile :

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.3'
gem 'sass'
gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'uglifier'

gem 'devise', '2.1.2'

gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'

gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 's3_swf_upload'

gem 'rails-i18n', '0.7.3'



group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :require => 'sqlite3'
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'binding_of_caller'
end


group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end

gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.pre2"
gem "haml"
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem "friendly_id", "~> 3.2.1"
gem "simple_form"
gem 'web-app-theme', '>= 0.6.2'
gem "mobile-fu"
gem 'inherited_resources'
gem 'settingslogic'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'

gem 'mechanize'
gem 'nokogiri'
```

*EDIT*

It works without style in paperclip config.

Answer (score 1):

It works now. The problem is, I have not intalled Imagemagick in my pc. Now since I installed and gave the path. It works like a charm :)